# Instance member 'result' cannot be used on type 'Regex.Match'

Tags: swift, cocoapods

I am updating my app with new features and I added the CSVImporter from Cocoapods into the app. However, there are some issues with the code about "Instance member 'result' cannot be used on type 'Regex.Match'". I would like to know how to fix it!

```
import Foundation

/// `Regex` is a swifty regex engine built on top of the NSRegularExpression api.
public struct Regex {
    // MARK: - Properties
     let regularExpression: NSRegularExpression

    // MARK: - Initializers
    /// Create a `Regex` based on a pattern string.
    ///
    /// If `pattern` is not a valid regular expression, an error is thrown
    /// describing the failure.
    ///
    /// - parameters:
    ///     - pattern: A pattern string describing the regex.
    ///     - options: Configure regular expression matching options.
    ///       For details, see `Regex.Options`.
    ///
    /// - throws: A value of `ErrorType` describing the invalid regular expression.
    public init(_ pattern: String, options: Options = []) throws {
        regularExpression = try NSRegularExpression(
            pattern: pattern,
            options: options.toNSRegularExpressionOptions
        )
    }

    // MARK: - Methods: Matching
    /// Returns `true` if the regex matches `string`, otherwise returns `false`.
    ///
    /// - parameter string: The string to test.
    ///
    /// - returns: `true` if the regular expression matches, otherwise `false`.
    public func matches(_ string: String) -> Bool {
        return firstMatch(in: string) != nil
    }

    /// If the regex matches `string`, returns a `Match` describing the
    /// first matched string and any captures. If there are no matches, returns
    /// `nil`.
    ///
    /// - parameter string: The string to match against.
    ///
    /// - returns: An optional `Match` describing the first match, or `nil`.
    public func firstMatch(in string: String) -> Match? {
        let firstMatch = regularExpression
            .firstMatch(in: string, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: string.utf16.count))
            .map { Match(result: $0, in: string) }
        return firstMatch
    }

    /// If the regex matches `string`, returns an array of `Match`, describing
    /// every match inside `string`. If there are no matches, returns an empty
    /// array.
    ///
    /// - parameter string: The string to match against.
    ///
    /// - returns: An array of `Match` describing every match in `string`.
    public func matches(in string: String) -> [Match] {
        let matches = regularExpression
            .matches(in: string, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: string.utf16.count))
            .map { Match(result: $0, in: string) }
        return matches
    }

    // MARK: Replacing
    /// Returns a new string where each substring matched by `regex` is replaced
    /// with `template`.
    ///
    /// The template string may be a literal string, or include template variables:
    /// the variable `$0` will be replaced with the entire matched substring, `$1`
    /// with the first capture group, etc.
    ///
    /// For example, to include the literal string "$1" in the replacement string,
    /// you must escape the "$": `\$1`.
    ///
    /// - parameters:
    ///     - regex: A regular expression to match against `self`.
    ///     - template: A template string used to replace matches.
    ///     - count: The maximum count of matches to replace, beginning with the first match.
    ///
    /// - returns: A string with all matches of `regex` replaced by `template`.
    public func replacingMatches(in input: String, with template: String, count: Int? = nil) -> String {
        var output = input
        let matches = self.matches(in: input)
        let rangedMatches = Array(matches[0..<min(matches.count, count ?? .max)])
        for match in rangedMatches.reversed() {
            let replacement = match.string(applyingTemplate: template)
            output.replaceSubrange(match.range, with: replacement)
        }

        return output
    }
}

// MARK: - ExpressibleByStringLiteral
extension Regex: ExpressibleByStringLiteral {
    /// Creates a new `Regex` based on a string literal.
    /// If the internal initialization fails, the code will crash without any option to handle the error.
    /// For safe `Regex` initialization, use the `init(_: String, options: Options) throws` overload instead.
    ///
    /// - parameter stringLiteral: The pattern string.
    public init(stringLiteral value: String) {
        do {
            try self.init(value)
        } catch {
            preconditionFailure("Not a valid regex: \(value)")
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - CustomStringConvertible
extension Regex: CustomStringConvertible {
    /// Returns a string describing the regex using its pattern string.
    public var description: String {
        return "Regex<\"\(regularExpression.pattern)\">"
    }
}

// MARK: - Equatable
extension Regex: Equatable {
    /// Determines the equality of to `Regex`` instances.
    /// Two `Regex` are considered equal, if both the pattern string and the options
    /// passed on initialization are equal.
    public static func == (lhs: Regex, rhs: Regex) -> Bool {
        return lhs.regularExpression.pattern == rhs.regularExpression.pattern &&
        lhs.regularExpression.options == rhs.regularExpression.options
    }
}

// MARK: - Hashable
extension Regex: Hashable {
    /// Returns a unique hash value for the `Regex` instance.
    public var hashValue: Int {
        return regularExpression.hashValue
    }
}

// MARK: - Options
extension Regex {
    /// `Options` defines alternate behaviours of regular expressions when matching.
    public struct Options: OptionSet {
        // MARK: - Properties
        /// Ignores the case of letters when matching.
        public static let ignoreCase = Options(rawValue: 1)

        /// Ignore any metacharacters in the pattern, treating every character as
        /// a literal.
        public static let ignoreMetacharacters = Options(rawValue: 1 << 1)

        /// By default, "^" matches the beginning of the string and "$" matches the
        /// end of the string, ignoring any newlines. With this option, "^" will
        /// the beginning of each line, and "$" will match the end of each line.
        public static let anchorsMatchLines = Options(rawValue: 1 << 2)

        /// Usually, "." matches all characters except newlines (\n). Using this,
        /// options will allow "." to match newLines
        public static let dotMatchesLineSeparators = Options(rawValue: 1 << 3)

        /// The raw value of the `OptionSet`
        public let rawValue: Int

        /// Transform an instance of `Regex.Options` into the equivalent `NSRegularExpression.Options`.
        ///
        /// - returns: The equivalent `NSRegularExpression.Options`.
        var toNSRegularExpressionOptions: NSRegularExpression.Options {
            var options = NSRegularExpression.Options()
            if contains(.ignoreCase) { options.insert(.caseInsensitive) }
            if contains(.ignoreMetacharacters) { options.insert(.ignoreMetacharacters) }
            if contains(.anchorsMatchLines) { options.insert(.anchorsMatchLines) }
            if contains(.dotMatchesLineSeparators) { options.insert(.dotMatchesLineSeparators) }
            return options
        }

        // MARK: - Initializers
        /// The raw value init for the `OptionSet`
        public init(rawValue: Int) {
            self.rawValue = rawValue
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - Match
extension Regex {
    /// A `Match` encapsulates the result of a single match in a string,
    /// providing access to the matched string, as well as any capture groups within
    /// that string.
    public class Match: CustomStringConvertible {
        // MARK: Properties
        /// The entire matched string.
        public lazy var string: String = {
            return String(describing: self.baseString[self.range])
        }()

        /// The range of the matched string.
        public lazy var range: Range<String.Index> = {
            return Range(self.result.range, in: self.baseString)!
        }()

        /// The matching string for each capture group in the regular expression
        /// (if any).
        ///
        /// **Note:** Usually if the match was successful, the captures will by
        /// definition be non-nil. However if a given capture group is optional, the
        /// captured string may also be nil, depending on the particular string that
        /// is being matched against.
        ///
        /// Example:
        ///
        ///     let regex = Regex("(a)?(b)")
        ///
        ///     regex.matches(in: "ab")first?.captures // [Optional("a"), Optional("b")]
        ///     regex.matches(in: "b").first?.captures // [nil, Optional("b")]
        public lazy var captures: [String?] = {
            let captureRanges = stride(from: 0, to: result.numberOfRanges, by: 1)
                .map(result.range)
                .dropFirst()
                .map { [unowned self] in
                    Range($0, in: self.baseString)
                }

            return captureRanges.map { [unowned self] captureRange in
                if let captureRange = captureRange {
                    return String(describing: self.baseString[captureRange])
                }

                return nil
            }
        }()

        private let result: NSTextCheckingResult

        private let baseString: String

        // MARK: - Initializers
        internal init(result: NSTextCheckingResult, in string: String) {
            precondition(
                result.regularExpression != nil,
                "NSTextCheckingResult must originate from regular expression parsing."
            )

            self.result = result
            self.baseString = string
        }

        // MARK: - Methods
        /// Returns a new string where the matched string is replaced according to the `template`.
        ///
        /// The template string may be a literal string, or include template variables:
        /// the variable `$0` will be replaced with the entire matched substring, `$1`
        /// with the first capture group, etc.
        ///
        /// For example, to include the literal string "$1" in the replacement string,
        /// you must escape the "$": `\$1`.
        ///
        /// - parameters:
        ///     - template: The template string used to replace matches.
        ///
        /// - returns: A string with `template` applied to the matched string.
        public func string(applyingTemplate template: String) -> String {
            let replacement = result.regularExpression!.replacementString(
                for: result,
                in: baseString,
                offset: 0,
                template: template
            )

            return replacement
        }

        // MARK: - CustomStringConvertible
        /// Returns a string describing the match.
        public var description: String {
            return "Match<\"\(string)\">"
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code and I have a screenshot for further details.
[Link of the screenshot of the error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0VBx.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying issue is the instance member `result` is being called from a lazy var.

This is an old error so not modern Swift/Xcode.

I would guess a `self.result` is required to make this go away.

With lazy vars you need to specify self for instance members and the type, as it cannot be inferred (at least this used to be the case).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It was really helpful and it was solved. However, now I have to deal with Apple Mach-O Linker Error...

Comment: Lol @KevinLau_DBS_OI_TEAM , that’s always the way.

Comment: My Apple Mach-O Linker Error is quite unique. When I search online, they all tell me to go to build settings and change the bitcode to no, however it doesn't work for me. They are referring to another error (ld), but mine is different. Could you possibly help me out again with this error? It would be much appreciated!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50022080/apple-mach-o-linker-error-static-not-ld refer to this link thanks!